# TestCafe: export command is not working in Linux

Tags: linux, jenkins, testing, environment-variables, testcafe

I am using testcafe for my automation.

According to the documentation Set Environment Variables 
I am using `set` for windows running locally and `export` for running the tests on a Linux environment using Jenkins job. 
In windows, it's working completely fine. But in Linux export command is not setting the environment variables.

The shell command I am using in windows `set ENV=staging& npx testcafe \"chrome:headless --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage\" automation_suite/tests`

The shell script command I am using in Jenkins to run on Linux 
Jenkins pipeline script

```
  stage('Run tests') {
   steps {
    sh 'npm run ci360:smoketest:chrome:headless'
   }
  }
```

The shell command

`npm run ci360:smoketest:chrome:headless` will automatically invoke the command

`export ENV=staging& npx testcafe \"chrome:headless --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage\" automation_suite/tests` which is defined in scripts section of package.json

not sure what's the issue here and I was stuck at this point. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In the Linux command, change the `&` to a `;`.

Comment: Also, it's not clear why you're escaping your quotation marks.  Are you escaping them from Jenkins?  It would be clearer if you either focused on the command as if it were specified directly to a shell *or* provided the full context for it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have updated the question.
I am escaping my quotation because the actual command defined in npm scripts is
`"ci360:smoketest:chrome:headless": "export ENV=staging& npx testcafe \"chrome:headless --no-sandbox --disable-dev-shm-usage\" automation_suite/tests`
In jenkins file i am just running the `npm run ci360:smoketest:chrome:headless` which will invoke the command defined in scripts.

Comment: Again, in the Linux command, change `&` to `;`.  This will yield a one-liner equivalent to what is described in the doc you linked.  If this does not resolve the issue, then it very likely has to do with the way you are launching the tests.  I do not have the Jenkins (or `npm`) expertise to assist with that side of things.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks buddy, it's working by replacing & with ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by replacing `&` with `;`